# Save current gap when pyomo model stops due to time limit

Tags: python, pyomo, gurobi

I have a pyomo model and want to compare the performance of solving it normally against solving a reduced model that I generate through an algorithm. I want to set a time limit and see either which one finishes first or if one or both does not finish in the time limit, which of both models reached the better solution by saving the gap value.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
solver_info = optimizer.solve(self.pyM, warmstart=warmstartHeuristic, tee=True, load_solutions=False)
self.solverSpecs['gap'] = solver_info.solution(0).gap
self.pyM.solutions.load_from(solver_info)
```

The second line of code is supposed to save the gap value. My test example for the normally solved model ended it optimization with gurobi with these lines:

```
    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

     0     0 21125.0674    0    5          - 21125.0674      -     -   60s
H    0     0                    192740.94072 21125.0674  89.0%     -  227s

Explored 1 nodes (56138 simplex iterations) in 300.02 seconds
Thread count was 3 (of 4 available processors)

Solution count 1: 192741 

Time limit reached
Best objective 1.927409407219e+05, best bound 2.112506743254e+04, gap 89.0397%
WARNING: Loading a SolverResults object with an 'aborted' status, but
    containing a solution

Status: aborted
Return code: 0
Message: Optimization terminated because the time expended exceeded the value specified in the TimeLimit parameter.
Termination condition: maxTimeLimit
Termination message: Optimization terminated because the time expended exceeded the value specified in the TimeLimit parameter.
Wall time: 300.0222430229187
Error rc: 0
Time: 301.3100845813751
```

which states that the solution has a gap of around 90%. But the value that is saved into the dictionary is zero. I am using:

Pyomo 5.7.2.
Gurobi 9.0.2

Isn't this gap value the MipGap or is this a bug? I took a look at the complete solver_info object and the bounds saved there would result in the correct gap, so I am a little bit confused.